# Setting custom action bar colors

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am writing my first app using Android Studio 1.02 and following an on-line tutorial. In the build.gradle file I have minSdkVersion 15. I'm having a problem with setting custom action bar colors.

As per the instructions I tried setting the theme in the manifest at the application level with  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light". The program would compile but not run on my phone (Android 4.4.2). After reading threads on this forum and else where I was never able to resolve this, but the tutorial showed how to point to custom theme with android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">

This worked, but not entirely. Below is my custom theme and colors value xml. The colors are all the same on purpose, for testing. The background color works, but the text shows up as white, no matter what values I put in there.

The other thing I had to do here to get this to compile was change all of the parent= references from parent="@style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText" to parrent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText"

Any help is appreciated.

Greg

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
    parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
    parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>


<color name="disabled_text">#9FFF</color>
<color name="actionbar_background">#b43004</color>
<color name="background">#b43004</color>
<color name="actionbar_text">#b43004</color>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use Toolbar instead ActionBar.

Comment: Perhaps Toolbar will come further in the tutorial.

Comment: I can't find any reference to a toolbar for android. Can you point me to something on-line? This thing is still not working and now with my screwing with it it has gotten worse.